# Extracting text from generic span tag nested within multiple div tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to grab the text (shown as a date) in the following piece of html code. The code `a1v2v3` changes depending on the page, so I cannot use that as a reference or use a css selector.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="mvp-collapse-content-box">
<div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-row"><div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-tag mvp-tag-default mvp-tag-checked" style="margin-left: -16px; visibility: hidden;">
<!----> <span class="mvp-tag-text">LIVE</span> 
<!----></div><span data-v-a1v2v3="" style="display: inline-block;">
                  2019.06.12 17:09
                  <br data-v-a1v2v3="">
```

Full HTML:

```
<div class="mvp-collapse-content-box">
<div data-v-a1v2v3="">
<div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-collapse mvp-collapse-simple">
<div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-collapse-item mvp-collapse-item-active" style="padding-left: 6px;">
<div class="mvp-collapse-header">
<!----> <div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-row-flex mvp-row-flex-middle">
<div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-col mvp-col-span-18 mvp-col-span-xs-16 mvp-col-span-sm-18 mvp-col-span-md-18 mvp-col-span-lg-18"><div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-tag mvp-tag-blue mvp-tag-checked" style="margin-left: -16px;">
<!----> <span class="mvp-tag-text mvp-tag-color-white">LIVE</span> 
<!----></div><div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="versionAndMemo">
<span data-v-a1v2v3="" style="display: inline-block; line-height: 26px; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px 1px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;">1.2.3.44</span>
<!----></div></div>
<div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-col mvp-col-span-6 mvp-col-span-xs-8 mvp-col-span-sm-6 mvp-col-span-md-6 mvp-col-span-lg-6"><div data-v-a1v2v3="" style="display: inline-block; float: right; margin-right: 6px;"><i data-v-a1v2v3="" class="lal la-download" style="font-size: 1.8em; margin-top: 8px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"></i></div>
<div data-v-a1v2v3="" style="float: right; margin-right: 22px;"><i data-v-a1v2v3="" class="lal la-link" style="font-size: 1.8em; margin-top: 8px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"></i></div></div></div></div> <div class="mvp-collapse-content" style="" data-old-padding-top="" data-old-padding-bottom="" data-old-overflow="">
<div class="mvp-collapse-content-box">
<div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-row"><div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-tag mvp-tag-default mvp-tag-checked" style="margin-left: -16px; visibility: hidden;">
<!----> <span class="mvp-tag-text">LIVE</span> 
<!----></div><span data-v-a1v2v3="" style="display: inline-block;">
                  2019.06.12 17:09
                  <br data-v-a1v2v3="">
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
        page = requests.get(app, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        for spantime in  soup.findAll("div", {"class": "mvp-collapse-content-box"}):
            print(spantime)
```

But nothing is being printed. I have also tried adding the following:

```
        page = requests.get(app, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        for spantime in  soup.findAll("div", {"class": "mvp-collapse-content-box"}):

            print(spantime.text)
            for span in  spantime.find_all('span', recursive=True):
                print(span.text)
```

But the neither of them prints anything. I have a feeling that it might have something to do with the `mvp-collapse-content-box` class that I've used - some of the div tags with that class do not necessarily have span tags, as shown in the Full HTML.

Comment: can you post proper html tag which you are looking after to fetch values?

Comment: @Kunduk Yes, but I wanted to illustrate that the class selector I am using includes some divs where there is no span tag. I'll cut out the irrelevant lines then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find_next() to find the span tag and use text property.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<div class="mvp-collapse-content-box">
<div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-row"><div data-v-a1v2v3="" class="mvp-tag mvp-tag-default mvp-tag-checked" style="margin-left: -16px; visibility: hidden;">
<!----> <span class="mvp-tag-text">LIVE</span> 
<!----></div><span data-v-a1v2v3="" style="display: inline-block;">
                  2019.06.12 17:09
                  <br data-v-a1v2v3="">'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
div=soup.find('div',class_="mvp-collapse-content-box")
print(div.find_next('span').find_next('span').text.strip())
```

### Output:

```
2019.06.12 17:09
```

Comment: While trying that with my full HTML, I get an error 'NoneType has no attribute find_next'. Maybe because some divs with that class do not contain span tags?

Comment: I tried using a try/except block but it ended up printing nothing.

Comment: in that case you have share your url to look into it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the link as it is only available on the internal network. But your code has helped me reach the answer yesterday so I'll mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always select a child tag like this:

```
 div = soup.find("div", { "class" : "mvp-collapse-content-box" })
 spans = div.findChildren("span" , recursive=False)
 for span in spans:
    print span
```

Comment: Hi, while trying that with my full HTML, I get an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findChildren'". Maybe because some divs with that class do not contain span tags? Should I use a try/catch block to prevent this?

Comment: Yes please do use try/catch.